# Problem with the application - Laravel 405 method not allowed

Tags: php, laravel

I need help. I will immediately point out that I did not write this application and I am new to these things.

I have an application built on laravel and a problem when executing this script: Accurately reads data from a JSON file into the Postgressql database:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\SettingsRequest;
use App\Settings;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\data;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use DateTime;

class SynchronizeController extends Controller
{
    protected $cgiWrapper = null;
    protected $csvImporter = null;

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Settings  $settings
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.synchronize.index');
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\SettingsRequest  $request
     * @param  \App\Settings  $settings
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('thefile')) {
            if ($request->thefile->getClientOriginalExtension() == 'json')
            {
                $content = file_get_contents($request->file('thefile'));
                $file_json = json_decode($content,true);
                $created_at = new DateTime();
                $created_at = $created_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $tableCount = 0;
                $insertTableNames = '';
                $insertColumns = '';
                $insertValues = '';
                foreach($file_json['data'] as $i => $v)
                {
                    DB::table($i)->delete();
                    foreach ($file_json['data'][$i] as $j => $g) {
                        $insertTableNames = 'INSERT INTO '.$i;
                        foreach ($file_json['data'][$i][$j] as $key => $value) {
                            $insertColumns = $insertColumns.$key.',';
                            $insertValues = $insertValues.'\''.$value.'\''.',';
                        }
                        $sqlQuery = $insertTableNames.' ('.$insertColumns.'created_at'.') '.'VALUES '.'('.$insertValues.'\''.$created_at.'\''.')';
                    
                        DB::insert($sqlQuery);
                    
                        $insertColumns = '';
                        $insertValues = '';
                    }
                    $tableCount++;
                }
                return Redirect::back()->with('tableCount',$tableCount);
            }
            else {
                return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['Format', 'Błędny format pliku! Tylko rozszerzenie .JSON!']);
            }
        }
        else {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['Plik', 'Nie wybrano pliku do importu!']);
        }
    }
}
```

I read that it could be a problem with the routes but I looked at the web.php file and I don't see an error:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->middleware(['auth', 'role:admin'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');

    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
    Route::get('users/delete/{user}', 'UserController@destroy')->name('users.delete');

    Route::get('settings', 'SettingsController@edit')->name('settings.edit');
    Route::post('settings', 'SettingsController@update')->name('settings.update');

    Route::get('synchronize', 'SynchronizeController@index')->name('synchronize.index');
    Route::post('synchronize', 'SynchronizeController@update')->name('synchronize.update');

    Route::get('images/models', 'ImagesController@models')->name('images.models');
    Route::get('images/structures', 'ImagesController@structures')->name('images.structures');
    Route::get('images/colors', 'ImagesController@colors')->name('images.colors');
    Route::get('images/hinges', 'ImagesController@hinges')->name('images.hinges');
    Route::get('images/accesories', 'ImagesController@accesories')->name('images.accesories');
    Route::get('images/tresholds', 'ImagesController@tresholds')->name('images.tresholds');
    Route::get('images/{doorModelCode}/framevariants', 'ImagesController@framevariants')->name('images.framevariants');
    Route::get('images/{doorModelCode}/stainedglass', 'ImagesController@stainedGlass')->name('images.stainedglass');
    Route::post('images/upload', 'ImagesController@upload')->name('images.upload');
    Route::post('images/delete', 'ImagesController@delete')->name('images.delete');

    Route::get('infos/lines', 'InfosController@lines')->name('infos.lines');
    Route::get('infos/collections', 'InfosController@collections')->name('infos.collections');
    Route::post('infos/lines', 'InfosController@lineStore')->name('infos.lines.store');
    Route::post('infos/collections', 'InfosController@collectionStore')->name('infos.collections.store');


});
```

I'll add the .htaccess file but honestly it's green at this and I need it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

:Location /*.php
Use php7 
:Location
```

Of course, the problem is that when loading data from the browser, I get the message: ERROR 405 Method not ALLOWED.

I have no idea where to look for what the problem is. The problem with the application appeared after some movements on the hosting server, allegedly only the ip address changed, but I had to add a new password to the postresa in the .env file. Maybe it's something server side not enabled?

So far it's nothing

Comment: _"I get the message: ERROR 405 Method not ALLOWED."_ - for what specific request?

Comment: above code works perfectly with laravel inbuilt development server? you checked it this?

Comment: When it invokes the sync command which is " Route::post('synchronize', 'SynchronizeController@update')->name('synchronize.update');"

Comment: When you say "invokes the sync command", do you mean when you send a POST request to the URL `/admin/synchronize`? Can you show us how you make the request when it fails? We need the full context of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change your route from a post to a put, if you are updating data it would be a PUT request. I hope this helps

```
Route::post('synchronize', 'SynchronizeController@update')->name('synchronize.update');
```

TO

```
Route::put('synchronize', 'SynchronizeController@update')->name('synchronize.update');
```

Comment: _"if you are updating data it would be a PUT request"_ - That's only true if they specifically make a PUT request, which they haven't mentioned.

Comment: Method not allowed usually happens when you send the request to a method using the incorrect type, sure it may not be the issue but making the assumption that's its a route that's accepting data to update something would suggest that its a PUT request.

Comment: My point was rather that the answer was a bit premature since we don't even know if they are doing PUT or not. And if you look at the majority of PHP sites, people tend to use POST for most (at least when they aren't building a public API).